# What happens during `begin; return; ensure`?

Tags: ruby

I was looking into the internals of a gem, and ran into the following pattern:

```
def foo
  begin
    return 'foo'
  ensure
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
foo
```

This will print the strings `'foo'` and `'bar'` to `STDOUT`. How does this happen? My naive understanding would be that when you encounter a `return` statement, then you pop the call off the stack and return the value specified by return. I would imagine that if this were the case, then you would not then be able to execute the `ensure` block. Obviously the `ensure` block is executed. I'm curious as to how this is happening.  How is this behavior implemented?

Comment: That is how `ensure` is designed to work. That is the whole point. Are you expecting particular implementation details of `ensure`? That probably depends on the Ruby implementation.

Comment: The question of the day: what would happen if you **`return` from `ensure`**?

Comment: According to the Ruby ISO Standard: "The _ensure-clause_ of a _body-statement_, if any, is always evaluated, even when the evaluation of _body-statement_ is terminated by a _jump-expression_."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way it's defined in MRI, more specifically in the function `rb_ensure` in [eval.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/02c1358be526e0fec672a420df80cd7d25ef1eae/eval.c#L1022-L1064) (I snipped the actual implementation, but essentially it just generates a Ruby execution context, executes the block in that context and then makes sure that all `ensure` blocks are run one after the other:

```
* Equivalent to <code>begin .. ensure .. end</code>.
 *
 * Calls the function \a b_proc with \a data1 as the argument,
 * then calls \a e_proc with \a data2 when execution terminated.
 * \return The return value of \a b_proc if no exception occurred,
 *   or \c Qnil if otherwise.
 * \sa rb_rescue
 * \sa rb_rescue2
 * \sa rb_protect
 * \ingroup exception
 */
VALUE
rb_ensure(VALUE (*b_proc)(ANYARGS), VALUE data1, VALUE (*e_proc)(ANYARGS), VALUE data2)
{
    ...
}
```

If you're interested in how the parser decides to call this faction, look at `parse.y` it's part of the rules for `bodystmt`.

Answer (score 1):

> when *you* encounter a `return` statement then *you*

When **MRI** encounters the `return` statement, it does **something**. Some interpreters might print `"FOO"` to the printer; that is located in your boss’ room :)

> pop the call off the stack and return the value specified by `return`

Almost. When **MRI** encounters the `return` statement, it *calls the `ensure` block if it exists* and **then** pops the call off the stack.

The thing is there is no mandatory rule that `return` must do something special, graved in stone. Ruby interpreter (and some others) does it that way.

Comment: While I like the printer idea, implementations that follow https://github.com/ruby/spec have a bit less liberty here ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKohl “_Some_ interpreters” might disrespect the _ruby_ spec :)

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers.  If I had decided to be lazy about things then this would have been it.  It turned out to be good for me to work through the source and the answer by @MichaelKohl led me to that.

Answer (score 0):

`return` assigns a value to the method, even if the execution goes trough `ensure` block.

For example:

```
def foo
  begin
    puts txt = 'foo'
    return txt
  ensure
    puts 'bar'
  end
  puts txt = 'baz'
  return txt
end

p foo
```

Puts "foo" and "bar" but not "baz". Also foo method returns the string "foo".